# How to texture a beveled curve without stretching

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

I would like to texture my trees without converting them to a mesh. I use the *use UV for mapping* option in the curve menu, but it is dependant on the distance between two "path points". How can I get a nice mapping without such stretching/squeezing :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The curve has same amount of edge loops between control points in the U direction of the curve (the setting you can set in the shape panel). UV space maps linearly to this, and changing this functionality would be hard if not impossible. Usually it's the desired functionality, preventing the textures sliding around if the curve is animated among other things.

You can however work around it by using two curves, one of which is just a straight line and holds the materials, textures, and resolution and bevel settings used for rendering. This curve then uses a curve modifier to copy the shape from another curve, which is used for just defining the shape of the final object. That way the rendered curve has uniform distribution of edge loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect :) However, the workaround is not easy to use. Each Branch of the tree has too get it's own duo of curve : the "shape and texture" curve and the deformation curve. Is there a way to have only one "shape and texture curve" that would be automatically "arrayed" to fit the length of the deformation curve ?