# How model a long tunnel

Tags: mesh, texturing, camera

In one small city exists underground, two level, tunnel system, partly overwhelmed now, ~200 meters longest diameter. I modeled it by meshing curve. Now I'm looking for idea how texture it with stone and some brick's walls. It is for Unity engine and first person model with enigmatic camera texture working ably so speed should be right with more advanced walls. Additionally how smart work inside tunnel - cameras setup?

[image: My current model]

Comment: Check this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/adding-a-texture-map-to-a-beveled-curve-or-path and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-to-texture-a-beveled-curve-without-stretching

Comment: Andrew Price did a good tutorial on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sROnLfkPgzA
In general you never create huge models for game assets. You generally create smaller chunks of them and compose them into a big scene within the game engine of choice.

Comment: In Neil Hirsig's [Blender course](http://gryllus.net/Blender/3D.html), the eighth ~.pdf tutorial is on the subject of modeling a cave. You might find useful information there.