# texture a curve

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves

I have a curve (and i don't wanna convert it to mesh) and i want to texture that curve:

[image]

Unfortunately my texture is getting stretched on the straight parts.

How can i have the same distance of the rings on the circle part and on the straight part?

shader nodes:

[image]

Comment: resampling curve via geo nodes seems to be the only solution :( or you can subdivide the straight parts to get a uniform vertex density (ok solution for simple curves)

Comment: no it isn't because then it is no curve anymore

Comment: It doesn't seem possible: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-to-texture-a-beveled-curve-without-stretching ... maybe you can try to subdivide the straight part

Comment: wow, that's so sad :( is there maybe an add-on which resamples a curve geonode can do? so that the distances between control points are equal? or wouldn't that help at all?

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5427 see Mapping T evenly on the curve AKA arc-length parameterization

Comment: Generate cooridinates option ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/adding-a-texture-map-to-a-beveled-curve-or-path

Comment: there is no "use uv for mapping" checkbox anymore...and i don't get it working. If you can...i would appreciate it if you show me how

Comment: ok, i would also accept a geometry nodes solution... :D

Comment: ...it is still possible to achieve the desired result. Guess what? With *Geometry Nodes*, hell yeah! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43146

Comment: @Chris Is this the look you are after? a curve with this texture https://imgur.com/a/cWTTjVj

Answer (score 5):

ok, this works for me now:

[image]

so i give the factor value to the group output and use that as uv value.

[image]

Comment: +1, the easiest way. In one direction. The other direction will not work like this, but for this purpose it is enough.

Comment: I still try to understand your solution 